# How do I make my start screen for my python game to load?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

SO I am trying to make a start screen for my game but it wont work, as soon as I start my game, The screen turns dark for around 3 seconds than the game just starts playing, I get no errors and nothing the game just starts playing. I am not really sure what to do and how to fix it,

https://gyazo.com/7ea9a5d3dba4cc8893421d1812479514 this is a video to show whats happening.

```
def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    print(click)
    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac,(x,y,w,h))

        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()         
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic,(x,y,w,h))

    smallText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)

        
def game_intro():

    intro = True

    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            #print(event)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
                
        window.fill((255,255,255))
        largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",115)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("A bit Racey", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((600/2),(600/2))
        window.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        button("GO!",150,450,100,50,green,bright_green,game_loop)
        button("Quit",550,450,100,50,red,bright_red,quitgame)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)
```

```
My Full code:




import pygame
pygame.init()

#this is screem height
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))

#know we put screem name
pygame.display.set_caption("Noobs first Game")






def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    print(click)
    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac,(x,y,w,h))

        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()         
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic,(x,y,w,h))

    smallText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)

        
def game_intro():

    intro = True

    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            #print(event)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
                
        window.fill(white)
        largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",115)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("A bit Racey", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((600/2),(600/2))
        window.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        button("GO!",150,450,100,50,green,bright_green,game_loop)
        button("Quit",550,450,100,50,red,bright_red,quitgame)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)
        









bg = pygame.image.load("New.png")

gg = pygame.image.load("lol.png")

Rule2 = pygame.image.load("one1.png")

Rule1 = pygame.image.load("two2.png")

Rule3 = pygame.image.load("three3.png")

Rule4 = pygame.image.load("four4.png")

Rule5 = pygame.image.load("five5.png")

Rule6 = pygame.image.load("six6.png")

#player class
class player:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 5
        self.isJump = False
        self.JumpCount = 10
        self.fall = 0
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)

class platform:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
        self.ss1 = pygame.image.load("Rock.png")
        self.ss1 = pygame.transform.scale(self.ss1,(self.ss1.get_width()//2,self.ss1.get_height()//2))
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 20 , self.y,58,60)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft=(self.x,self.y)

        player_rect = self.ss1.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)
        player_rect.centerx += 70
        player_rect.centery += 88
        window.blit(self.ss1,player_rect)
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 20 , self.y,58,60)

class item:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
        self.ss1 = pygame.image.load("H6.png")
        self.ss1 = pygame.transform.scale(self.ss1,(self.ss1.get_width()//2,self.ss1.get_height()//2))
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        window.blit(self.ss1,self.rect)
        
        
class wall:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)


#draw player
white = (255,255,255)
player1 = player(255,400,30,30,white)

darkred = (200,0,0)

darkgreen = (0,200,0)

item1 = item(200,-500,50,50,white)
item2 = item(250,250,50,50,white)
item3 = item(330,-1030,50,50,white)
item4 = item(400,-2290,50,50,white)
item5 = item(300,-1600,50,50,white)
item6 = item(200,130,50,50,white)
item7 = item(230,-1830,50,50,white)
item8 = item(300,0,50,50,white)
item9 = item(330,-1440,50,50,white)
item10 = item(20,-160,50,50,white)

items = [item1,item2,item3,item4,item5,item6,item7,item8,item9,item10]

green = (0,255,0)
orange = (255,0,0)
platform1 = platform(100,300,10,60,orange)
platform2 = platform(5,200,10,60,orange)
platform3 = platform(5,400,10,60,orange)
platform4 = platform(100,100,10,60,orange)
platform5 = platform(5,-50,10,60,orange)
platform6 = platform(100,-200,10,60,orange)
platform7 = platform(5,400,60,600,orange)
platform8 = platform(300,-2430,10,60,orange)
platform9 = platform (350,-340,10,60,orange)
platform10 = platform (100,-470,10,60,orange)

platform13 = platform(330,-600,10,60,orange)
platform14 = platform(100,-790,10,60,orange)
platform15 = platform(330,-990,10,60,orange)
platform16 = platform(70,-1130,10,60,orange)
platform17 = platform(200,-1340,10,60,orange)
platform18 = platform(400,-1500,10,60,orange)
platform19 = platform(300,-1700,10,60,orange)
platform20 = platform(100,-1950,10,60,orange)
platform21 = platform (350,-2140,10,60,orange)
platform22 = platform (100,-2270,10,60,orange)
platform23 = platform(0,-2500,60,500,green)


#walls
platform11 = wall (485,-9600,10000,10,orange)
platform12 = wall (0,-9600,10000,10,orange)
wall1 = wall (0,400,60,500,orange)
wall2 = wall (0,-2500,60,500,green)
wall3 = wall (485,-9600,10000,10,orange)
wall4 = wall (0,-9600,10000,10,orange)


walls = [wall1,wall2]



platforms = (platform1,platform2,platform3,platform4,platform5,platform6,platform7,platform8,platform9,platform10,platform13,platform14,platform15,platform16,platform17,platform18,platform19,platform20,platform21,platform22,platform23)

#window
def redrawwindow():
    window.fill((0,0,0))

    window.blit(bg,(0,0))

    #draw plyer
    player1.draw()
    platform11.draw()
    platform12.draw()
    wall3.draw()
    wall4.draw()
    for platform in platforms:
        platform.draw()
    for item in items:
        item.draw()
    for wall in walls:
        wall.draw()

# the score draw it on the screen
    window.blit(text,textRect)
    

fps = (60)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


font  = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",30)
score = 0
text = font.render("Coins = "+str(score),True,(255,255,255))
textRect = text.get_rect()
textRect.center = ((100,40))

def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    print(click)
    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac,(x,y,w,h))

        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()         
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic,(x,y,w,h))

    smallText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)

        
def game_intro():

    intro = True

    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            #print(event)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
                
        window.fill((255,255,255))
        largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",115)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("A bit Racey", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((600/2),(600/2))
        window.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        button("GO!",150,450,100,50,green,bright_green,game_loop)
        button("Quit",550,450,100,50,red,bright_red,quitgame)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)
        
        

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(fps)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        



    # coin collisions
    for item in items:
        for one in range(len(items)-1,-1,-1):
            if player1.rect.colliderect(items[one].rect):
                del items[one]
                score += 1
                text = font.render("Coins = "+str(score),True,(255,255,255))
                textRect.center = ((100,40))
        
    #walls
    if player1.rect.colliderect(platform11) and player1.rect.colliderect(platform12):
        player1.x = 40

        # this makes you scroll up
    if player1.y < 250:
        player1.y += 1
        #platforms
        for platform in platforms:
            platform.y += player1.speed

        for item in items:
            item.y += player1.speed

        for wall in walls:
            wall.y += player1.speed
            #walls
        platform11.y += player1.speed
        platform12.y += player1.speed

        # this makes you scroll down
    if player1.y > 450:
        player1.y -= player1.fall
        for platform in platforms:
            platform.y -= player1.fall
        platform11.y -= player1.fall
        platform12.y -= player1.fall


        for item in items:
            item.y -= player1.fall

        for wall in walls:
            wall.y -= player1.fall
    #keys
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    


    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_a]and player1.x > player1.speed:
        player1.x -= player1.speed

    if keys[pygame.K_d]and player1.x <500 - player1.height - player1.speed:
        player1.x += player1.speed

    if keys[pygame.K_w]and player1.y > player1.speed:
        player1.y -= player1.speed

    if keys[pygame.K_s]and player1.y <500 - player1.width - player1.speed:
        player1.y += player1.speed

    if not player1.isJump:
        player1.y += player1.fall
        player1.fall += 1
        player1.isJump = False

        collide = False
        # this part lets you jump on platform
        for platform in platforms:
            if player1.rect.colliderect(platform.rect):
                collide = True
                player1.isJump = False
                player1.y = platform.rect.top - player1.height + 1
                if player1.rect.right > platform.rect.left and player1.rect.left < platform.rect.left - player1.width:
                    player1.x = platform.rect.left - player1.width
                if player1.rect.left < platform.rect.right and player1.rect.right > platform.rect.right + player1.width:
                    player1.x = platform.rect.right
    
            

            if player1.rect.bottom >= 500:
                collide = True
                player1.isJump = False
                player1.JumpCount = 10
                player1.y = 500 - player1.height

        if collide:
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                player1.isJump = True
            player1.fall = 0


    else:
        if player1.JumpCount >= 0:
            player1.y -= (player1.JumpCount*abs(player1.JumpCount))*0.3
            player1.JumpCount -= 1
        else:
            player1.JumpCount = 10
            player1.isJump = False

        

    redrawwindow()
    if player1.rect.colliderect(platform6):
        window.blit(Rule3,(-150,-80))
        
    if player1.rect.colliderect(platform2.rect):
        window.blit(Rule1,(-30,0))
        
    if player1.rect.colliderect(platform23.rect):
        window.blit(gg,(100,100))
        
    if player1.rect.colliderect(platform7.rect):
        window.blit(Rule2,(-70,0))

        
    if player1.rect.colliderect(platform1.rect):
        window.blit(Rule4,(-40,100))

    if player1.rect.colliderect(platform14.rect):
        window.blit(Rule5,(-50,0))

    if player1.rect.colliderect(platform17.rect):
        window.blit(Rule6,(-50,0))

    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
game_intro()
```

Comment: Why are calling `game_intro()` after the main game loop? Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

your game is working fine for me
since i don't have the photos ("101.png","rock.png") i couldn't load the game though i replaced them with a different photos. seems it works!

the game just loads fast and fine when i tried it.

if you want to show a loading text use this

```
TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Loading...", largeText)
TextRect.center = ((600/2),(600/2))
window.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your game is quitting before the intro:

```
pygame.quit()
game_intro()
```

Call `game_intro()` before the main game loop.